# Match function in VBA doesn't work with percentages

Tags: excel, vba, match

I am doing an index match lookup in VBA and it works perfectly when normal numbers are used but when it's formatted as a percentages it does not work, it throws an error. How do I solve this?

```
   Sub TOP10() 'doesnt work on percentages

     Dim rngTestArea As Range
    Dim i, j As Long
     Dim MyResult As String


  lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngTestArea = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("K11:K" & lastRow)



 j = 0

 For i = 1 To 10

      j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rngTestArea, i)
      Location =  Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("C11:C" & lastRow), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(j, rngTestArea, 0), 1)
      geodis = geodis & Location & " - " & j & ","

Next i



MsgBox geodis



End Sub
```

Comment: this may help (or not): when you use anything other than `0` in the last match argument you need to consider sorting the data in the appropriate way (ascending \ descending)

Comment: There is also a chance that the number you use (that is displayed as a percentage) is actually a long floating point one. If you are trying to do an exact match -- it will almost never have the one exactly equivalent to the last decimal point (due to high precision). What you can do is to copy formatted percentage numbers with one or two decimal points into a separate column as strings and try to match against that.

Comment: Try dividing the number by 100 - if you're searching for 90% it will be stored as 0.9 on the worksheet.

Comment: yes they are very precise percentages, i do only need it to 1 or 2 decimals though. This is to automate a process and the document will always have a highly precise percentage such as 2.24101235446119%

Comment: scratch that last comment of mine, you pick the number up from the spreadsheet... change `j` to a double as 99% is stored as 0.99, as a long it will round the number you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed the value `2.24101235446119%` in cell K11, and a formula in cells below that: `=K11-0.01` down to row 111 (plus values in column C to find the last row).

This code returned 1 for Location - I've changed `j` to a double, `i` as a long and declared a few missing variables.  Other than that it's  your exact code.

```
Sub TOP10() 'doesnt work on percentages

     Dim rngTestArea As Range
     Dim i As Long, j As Double
     Dim MyResult As String
     Dim lastrow As Long
     Dim Location As Variant
     Dim geodis As String

    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngTestArea = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("K11:K" & lastrow)

    j = 0

    For i = 1 To 10

        j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rngTestArea, i)
        Location = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("C11:C" & lastrow), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(j, rngTestArea, 0), 1)
        geodis = geodis & Location & " - " & j & ","
    Next i

    MsgBox geodis

End Sub
```

Comment: works! i just changed J to a double and it now works as intended, thank you and the rest for the help. My rep isnt high enough to allow me to tick this

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't duplicate your exact problem ... except that I couldn't get it to run with out declaring Location and geodis as Variant (I also pulled the match out to see what was going on there).
After that, I got it to run with percentages.  Here are the values in K11:K25 that I tested with:  (I didn't have your data, so I had to end my last row with 26 for testing.)

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0.25
5
5800%
58
5
52
88

Here is what I used to debug your code that ran:

```
Sub TOP10() 'doesnt work on percentages

Dim rngTestArea As Range
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim MyResult As String
Dim Location As Variant
Dim geodis As Variant
Dim match As Variant


lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow = 26
Set rngTestArea = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("K11:K" & lastRow)

j = 0
Debug.Print rngTestArea.Address

For i = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print "i: " & i
    j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Large(rngTestArea, i)
    Debug.Print "j: " & j
    match = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(j, rngTestArea, 0)
    Debug.Print "match: " & match
    Location = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("GEODISTRIBUTION").Range("C11:C" & lastRow), match, 1)
    Debug.Print "Location: " & Location
    geodis = geodis & Location & " - " & j & ","
    Debug.Print "geodis: " & geodis

Next i


 Debug.Print geodis
'MsgBox geodis



End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend using `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`. The former can return an error without raising it (i.e., if the match isn't found), which means you can do easy local error handling without `GoTo/Resume` statements. You'd have to `Dim match as Variant` though, to do that.

Comment: Good recommendation!  @DavidZemens   ... I would like to add to that a bit of coding cleanup:  `Dim ws As Worksheet`  `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GEODISTRIBUTION")`  then your code would be more readable:  `lastRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: 4.35%
9.26%
0.50%
0.54%
0.54%
2.24%
2.81%
0.90%
0.04%
1.23%
3.11%
0.00%
4.67%
1.38%
0.69%
0.88%
0.31%
4.18%
0.12%
0.23%
4.77%
0.99% - these are the sort of numbers i am not getting to work. Whole numbers are working perfectly

Comment: I put your data in, and it ran flawless.  Here is what was in my Watches window:  `$K$11:$K$32
i: 10
j: 0
match: 12
Location: 0.009
geodis: 0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,
0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,0.009 - 0,

`

Comment: DId you see where I changed i, j to int also where I added: `Dim Location As Variant
Dim geodis As Variant
Dim match As Variant`?